# What does 459 means?

Tags: riddle

Ok so a guy texted 459 and then sent his lockscreen with the numbers and the letters below like abc below the no.1 and idk what that means so can anyone help?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a puzzle or related to puzzles in any way, so it has been closed.

Answer (score 6):

The letters below the 4 are GHI, below the 5 JKL, and below the 9 WXYZ. No three-letter word can be formed with one letter from each in the appropriate order, so probably your correspondent intended a three-letter initialism. Maybe GKX for "Get Katie's xylophone." No? How about "ILY" for "I love you"?

Comment: "I love you" seems too far-fetched in place of the obvious Get Katie's xylophone, but have an upvote.